# ContextMenuStrip is Disabled within a Modal Form

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog, contextmenustrip

I have encountered some bizarre behavior when trying to implement a context menu on a DataGridView that lives in a modal dialog (custom Winform shown using .ShowDialog() method).

When I add the context menu to the DataGridView (using the relevant property), within the designer I am able to edit items, assign events, and everything else you'd expect.

When I launch my form, the context menu is disabled. It appears when right clicking, but takes no inputs and doesn't show the mouse hover colors. After some trial and error, I found that this is only the case when I display the form as a modal dialog using .ShowDialog() and not .Show().

I have no idea why this would be the expected behavior; has anyone else encountered this before? If so, can you explain why this works like this? And is there a workaround that will allow me to use ContextMenuStrips on modal dialogs...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was not anything like I was expecting. On the modal form's startup, I had changed the context menu's visibility to true... I meant to do that to another control. For whatever reason that was the source of the problem.